# Android tablet missed wireless debugging

Tags: adb, android-12, vnc-server, adbwireless

My tablet is honor with android 12. when trying to stop phantom kill apps to make vncserver work, it keep stoping the server.
I tried to use adb to stop phantom killing apps but the tablet developer options don't have wireless debugging option.
Is there any other solution?

*Enabling developer options
*Did not find wireless debugging.